# Maven based JAX WS Project cannot be run in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, jboss

I followed this tutorial to create a JAX-WS web service in Eclipse:

```
http://sourceforge.net/p/eclipse-jaxws/wiki/Home/
```

It creates three projects:

```
MyApp-core
MyApp-main
MyApp-webdeploy
```

The fact is that when I right click on any of these projects, none of them has the option Run_As->Run_On_Server.

How can I run this webservice in Tomcat or JBoss and check that it work?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse JEE ? If you go to Help -> About, you should see something like this: "Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers."

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the project and go to `Properties > Project Facets`.Choose the appropriate module for your JAX WS project that will enable the run on server option. For a web project, it would be **Dynamic web module**. In your case, the module would be any webservices module. eg. Weblogic webservices

Answer (score 0):

From the URL that you shared

1. **main project** is the parent project. This does not have any code, but is used only to manage maven targets of the child projects
2. **core project** is child of -main project. This project has all the business logic. By default one Hello service is created in this project.
3. **webdeploy project** is Web project. This project has all the Spring and other configuration files which should are required for Web Services

So my best guess is that *web-deploy project* is the one that is deployable. Although you would need to configure it a bit with the core-project since it contains the actual web-service interface and Implemantation.